# Change CD-ROM via virsh

Tags: linux-kvm

I have a KVM virtual machine that is managed via libvirsh. Now I want to use a different ISO image inside the VM.

*How do I change the DVD in the virtual drive using `virsh`?*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add CDROM:

```
attach-disk guest01 /root/disc1.iso hdc --driver file --type cdrom
--mode readonly
```

Change CDROM:

```
attach-disk guest01 /root/disc2.iso hdc --driver file --type cdrom
--mode readonly
```

Remove CDROM:

```
 attach-disk guest01 " " hdc --driver file --type cdrom
 --mode readonly
```

Comment: Thanks, rkthr. I test this next week and come back here. +1 anyway :-)

Comment: Thanks for tip. For me it works but only if I remove '--driver file' from the command (version of `virsh`: 0.9.2).

Comment: I had to add `--config` to the command. Probably due to the fact that the guest wasn't originally configured with a cdrom. This addressed the following: `error: internal error: No device with bus 'ide' and target 'hdc'. cdrom and floppy device hotplug isn't supported by libvirt`.

Comment: virsh attach-disk virtual.host.name /tank/kvm/iso/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso hda --type cdrom --mode readonly

Comment: It seems that the domain must be started to attach a new source for the cdrom.

Comment: All I get for this is "Operation not supported: cdrom/floppy device hotplug isn't supported". (virsh version 5.0.0, libvirtd 5.0.0-4). Any idea why that is?

Comment: FYI: I got `error: unsupported configuration: unsupported driver name 'file' for disk 'sdb'` and had to use `--driver qemu` instead

Answer (score 24):

In libvirt 0.9.12 and maybe earlier, a command `change-media` exists:

```
change-media <domain> <path> [<source>] [--eject] [--insert] [--update] [--current] [--live] [--config] [--force]
```

Change CD:

```
change-media guest01 hdb /pool/disc.iso
```

Eject CD:

```
change-media guest01 hdb --eject
```

Comment: This is the right command when using SATA controller for CD-ROM.

Comment: This worked for SATA CDROM: `virsh change-media guest01 sdb /var/lib/libvirt/images/disc.iso`

Comment: +1. This works on not started vms, and very convenient in case vm cannot start because iso file is missing:
virsh start testingvm
error: Failed to start domain testingvm
error: Cannot access storage file '/ISO/virtio-win-0.1.229.iso': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I tried the attach-disk command and it didn't work for me. However, I found this doc on fedora which asks you to use the "update-device" command. This worked for me, and you can find it at [Attaching and updating a device with virsh](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Attaching_and_updating_a_device_with_virsh.html). Here are the steps:

- Create an XML file:

  ```
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
  <readonly/>
  <alias name='ide0-1-0'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
  </disk>
  ```

Make sure you don't have the `<source>` tag in your definition

- Update the device:

  ```
  virsh update-device <guest name> <XML file name>
  ```

Comment: That would remove the device, not change the CD as the OP asks. It's also badly copied from your link - it's malformed XML as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to export existing configuration:

```
virsh dumpxml guest_name > config.xml
```

Then you have to open file and copy cdrom section and add the line with iso image path like

```
<source file='some.iso'/>
```

So the result is something like

```
<disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
   <source file='some.iso'/>
   <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
   <backingStore/>
   <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
   <readonly/>
   <alias name='ide0-0-1'/>
   <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
 </disk>
```

and save it as cdrom.xml.

After that:

```
virsh update-device guest_name cdrom.xml

#Device updated successfully
```